# Prevent background image overflowing on large mobile screens

Tags: html, css, slick.js

I have a div with a background image set to it. It looks completely fine on smaller mobile screens.

However, as I move to larger and longer mobile screens, the image overflows from the sides. Basically some part of the image gets cut on larger mobile screens. How can I prevent this? And can I do it without editing the image itself?

Here's the website: https://www.elevarsports.com/pages/elevar-arc-racer-v2-beta#

This is the class to look at `.es-element-hero-imgtxt-mobile-img`.

I have already tried setting `max-width: 100%` but that doesn't do anything.

These are examples:

iPhone 6/7/8 (how it's supposed to look on all mobile screens

[image]

iPhone XS Max (how it looks on bigger and longer screens)

[image]

Note: I'm using Firefox as my browser.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 720/900) {
    .es-shoe-landing-hero .slide-1 {
        background-size: contain !important;
        background-position: top !important;
        background-color: #000;
    }
}
```

This changes how the first hero slide's background image is sized and positioned. `720/900` is the dimensions of the image and is being used to determine an aspect ratio at which this style is applied.

However, then your problem becomes that the image isn't tall enough for the view.

Comment: While this does ensure the image doesn't clip, like you said it doesn't take up the full height of it's parent container. Any way to continue using ```background-size:cover;``` and achieve this?

Comment: @jaimish11 The image is either going to be too wide or too tall. There's no getting around that. If possible, remove the text from the image and have it as part of the HTML. That way you have more control over them. (Really it should be split into three pieces: The text, the shoe, and the abstract background. That way you can have the text always at the top and just wide enough; the shoe always center; and the background always cover.)